# Bootstrap Firefox on Mac media query breakpoint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm struggling with a big deal.
Mac os, FF vers. 29 (also with previous versions).

I have a responsive website with bootstrap. 
It works fine on every browser BUT...
On Mac with FF, exactly at the pixel when the media queries have to change (eg: max-width: 600 px , resize the window until the html element has a width of exactly 600px), everithing breaks (specially the divs with visible-xs and hidden-xs), this also happen on every media query breakpoint: 1025px, 1200px..

Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Could you paste your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved injecting a different css via javascript only if is FF on Mac with the media queries augmented of 1 pixel....so ugly but was the fastest way and it works if someone has a better solution, go on!!!